# a worker process with process id of serving application pool has requested a recycle iis 8

Tags: asp.net, iis, server, configure, application-pool

I have a server with these configuration :
[image]

We have a huge traffic on our server ,My application is programmed by ASP MVC.And i configured the iis by these properties as you can see :

[image]

And
[image]

And

[image]

With these recycling setting :

[image]

But my problem:
Everything works fine for some minutes but after some minutes the CPU take 100 usage for 1 minutes .i trace the problem and i found this :

[image]

When the cpu takes the 100 usage my memory tries to recycling.So why ?And which part of application pool should be changed .?

As a note:My shutdown limit time was 90s but i changed it to 180 ,and this changing caused that the problem occurs fewer .

Comment: First image, look under CPU, you have configured CPU Limit 95 and you have mentioned Kill, this is causing worker process to be killed. However, There is no solution unless you find out which part of application is causing high CPU, try to use CDN and serve static content apart from your server. Make sure there is no infinite loop, and also make sure all diposable objects are closed properly.

Comment: @AkashKava as i said i think the recycling causes this error not my application